# Find the number of functions which are onto

Tags: functions

> Given a function $f:A\to B$ where $A=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $B=\{6,7,8\}$. Find the number of functions $y=f(x)$ which are onto.
>
> (A)243 (B)93  (C)150 (D)None of these

**My Approach:**

Since the function is said to be onto each element in set A has an image in set B. There are 5 elements in set A, and each element in set A can take any of the 3 values of B, so for each element in A there are 3 possibilities. So, total number of functions is $3^5=243$ by multiplication theorem.

But the answer is given as 150 (option (C)).

How it this possible, please explain.

Comment: But all of those 243 functions are not onto,like a function which takes 6 everywhere,so please count it carefully.

Comment: You can think that let say all the number can goes to particular one number in set b it can be 6,or7,or8 in that way yiu have to think

Comment: There are $3^5$ functions total but not all of them are onto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since the function is said to be onto each element in set A has an image in set B.

That's not what onto means.  That simply describes that $f$ is a function.

Onto means that every element of set B has a pre-image in set A.

> There are 5 elements in set A, and each element in set A can take any of the 3 values of B,

Not entirely, *some* element must take each value of $B$.  If $1\mapsto 6; 2\mapsto 6$ and $3\mapsto 6$ then neither $4$ nor $5$ can map to $6$. And if $4\mapsto 7$ then $5$ *must* map to $8$ and has no choice at all. So it's not that independent.

> so for each element in A there are 3 possibilities. So, total number of functions is $3^5=243$ by multiplication theorem.

Yes, that is the total number of *functions*.  But not all functions are onto.  So the number of *onto* function is somewhat less.

Consider all the functions that get mapped to $6$.  It can be as few as $1$ (at least one must) and as many as $3$ (at least $1$ must map to $7$ or $8$).  If there are $k$ that map to $6$, there are ${5 \choose k}$ chooses of which elements they are.

Now of the remaining $5-k$ then how many map to $7$.  there must be at least $1$ and at most $5-k-1$.  If there are $j$ that map into $7$ there are ${5-k \choose j}$ ways to choose them.

And there are $5-k-j$ remaining that all must map to $8$.

So there are $\sum_{k=1}^3 ({5\choose k}\cdot \sum_{j=1}^{5-k - 1}{5-k\choose j})$

${5\choose 1}({4\choose 1} + {4\choose 2} + {4\choose 3}) + {5\choose 2}({3\choose 1} + {3\choose 2}) + {5\choose 3}({2\choose 1}) =$

$5(4 + 6 + 4) + 10(3 + 3) + 10(2) =$

$70 + 60 + 20 = 150$.

......

But probably an easier way is inclusion exclusion.

There are $3^5$ total functions. But we must rule out the ones where only two of the values are mapped to.  There are ${3 \choose 2} =3$ choices as to which $2$ are not mapped to. And there are $2^5$ ways they can be mapped.  So that is $3^5 - 3*2^5$.

But the function where only one value is mapped to where removed *twice*.  For example.  I counted and removed the function $f(x) = 6$ when I was counting the functions where nothing is mapped to  $7$ and I also counted and removed it when I was counting the functions where nothing is mapped to $8$.  So I need to add these function *back*.

These are the function where all values of $A$ are mapped to a single value of $B$.  There are ${3\choose 1}=3$ choices for what value is mapped to and there are $1^5$ ways to map them.

So there are $3^5 - 3*2^5 + 3*1^5$ onto functions.

To be more technical there are ${3\choose 3}(3-0)^5 - {3\choose 2}(3-1)^5 + {3\choose 1}(3-2)^5$.

Any way.... $3^5 - 3*2^5 + 3*1^5 = 243 - 96 + 3 = 150$.

Answer (score 3):

One of the $243$ functions from $A$ to $B$ sends every element to $6$.  Neither $7$ nor $8$ are in the range of the function, so it is not onto $B$.  You need to count the functions that send at least one element to each of $6,7,8$.  This is easiest done by inclusion-exclusion.  Start with the $243$ functions, subtract all those that skip one of the elements in $B$ in their range, then note that you have subtracted the ones like my example that have just one element in their range twice, so add them back once.

Answer (score 2):

Number of onto function are $$ = {3}^5 -{ {3}\choose{2} }{2}^5 + { {3}\choose{1}}{1}^5 $$

$$ = 150 $$

This is from inclusion and exclusion principles.

Answer (score 1):

**Case 1:** Exactly one number $b\in B$ has exactly one preimage $a\in A$.

In this case, we have three choices for $b$. Now fix $b$, say $b:=b_0$. For the preimage $a$ of $b_0$, there are $5$ possibilities. The two other numbers in $B$ must have two preimages each, because of the requirement in this case 1. So, for each fixed preimage $a_0$ of $b_0$, there are $4 \choose 2$ possibilities for the preimages of the other two numbers of $B$. Hence, there are $3 \cdot 5 \cdot {4 \choose 2}=90$ functions in case 1.

**Case 2:** Exactly two numbers $b \in B$ have exactly one preimage $a \in A$. That is equivalent to: Exactly one number $c \in B$ has three preimages.

We have three possibilities for $c$, and $5 \choose 3$ for its preimages. Now, there are two numbers left in $A$ and in $B$, which gives 2 possibilities for the preimages of the other two numbers in $B \backslash \{c\}$. Hence, there are $3\cdot {5 \choose 3} \cdot 2 =60$ functions in case 2.

Adding up both numbers gives $90+60=150$ functions that are onto.